# ubuntu one disconnects after some time

Tags: ubuntu-one

my ubuntu one deamon keeps disconnecting, it tries to connect for few seconds, 
gets connected for few seconds then goes offline.
i tried

u1sdtool -q

u1sdtool --start

u1sdtool -c

still no remedy
How to solve it?

thanx

Comment: Yeah, I know. Same happened to me. Best to use another service as the bug reports about that all get thrown onto a big pile to fix when someone's got some spare time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the servers are under heavy load and clients get disconnected and reconnect. This is unfortunately going to remain a problem until we can resolve these issues.